# Calling instance method in Java

Tags: java, android

Following this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex2.html

In Step 2, this method gets called:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

which is a public method of Activity. Now, I'm a bit of a Java newbie here - I thought if you wanted to call an instance method of a superclass you needed to preface it with **this**. E.g.

```
this.registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Is it just a style thing here? Is there any difference between

```
this.registerForContextMenu
```

and simply

```
registerForContextMenu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

You don't have to use `this.`, but it is often done anyway to make the code clearer.

For one thing, it makes it easy to tell if a method is `static` or not if you use the convention of calling instance methods like this:

```
this.registerForContextMenu()
```

and `static` methods like this:

```
ClassName.staticRegisterForContextMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to use `this`. If you ommit it it is assumed you called method in `this` scope. One particular example when `this` may help could be i.e.:

```
Boolean someVar;
public function setMe( Boolean someVar ) {
  this.someVar = someVar;
}
```

In this case, w/o `this` you would get the error.

Answer (score 1):

To call a method of  superclass either you need  **object of superclss** or keyword **super** .
eg.

```
superObject.superclassMethod();
    super.superclassMethod();
```

**this** is a reference of the current object. **this** can be used to call method of a class in which it is used. **this** can never be used to call a superclass method.

As for

```
this.registerForContextMenu()
```

and

```
registerForContextMenu()
```

no such difference. you can use either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct for calling a method on the current (this) instance of the class. Non private methods are inherited from super classes, so you can use the same syntax to call such methods.